# Updating a Workflow assembly in CRM 4.0

Tags: plugins, workflow, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I have created a workflow assembly for Microsoft CRM 4.0, and uploaded it to the server, storing it in the database, using the Plugin Registration Tool v2.2 from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/crmplugin .

So far all's well and good, I use it in a workflow, and determine I have some bugs.

I fix them, and update the assembly using the above mentioned Plugin Registration Tool.

From the error messages I am getting, the old assembly is still running.

I have even tried deleting the workflow, unregistering the assembly, re-registering the assembly, and re-creating the workflow, with the same results.

Is there something else I need to do to get it to use the new dll? wait ten minutes? shake a stick at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried restarting the CRM Asynchronous Service?

Comment: I figured that out late last night, but I'm gonna give you the rep. I have been restarting that service and doing an IISReset.

Comment: I'd also continue to delete the workflow and create a new one each time you register the new assembly. I've seen workflows continue to run code that I'd manually deleted from the database before :)

Comment: It seems that if you unpublish and re-publish, it's good. However, if you change the assembly version on your dll, you will have to re-create the step calling your dll or it won't publish.  Thanks for your help. I'm pretty sure this won't be my last question on workflows and plugins today. I'm going to be building up the knowledge base on this one..